# How can I check from Ruby whether a process with a certain pid is running?

Tags: ruby, process, pid

If there is more than one way, please list them.  I only know of one, but I'm wondering if there is a cleaner, in-Ruby way.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

If it's a process you expect to "own" (e.g. you're using this to validate a pid for a process you control), you can just send sig 0 to it.

```
>> Process.kill 0, 370
=> 1
>> Process.kill 0, 2
Errno::ESRCH: No such process
    from (irb):5:in `kill'
    from (irb):5
>>
```

Comment: Interesting approach!  I'll investigate this.

Comment: dang, beat me to it.

I saw the "new answers have been posted" thing and my heart sank :(

Comment: But what's signal 0?  A noop?

Comment: From my man page: A value of 0, however, will cause error checking to be performed (with no signal being sent).  This can be used to check the validity of pid.

Comment: Dang, was looking at signals man page, etc.  Didn't think to look at kill's manpage.  :)  Thanks, Dustin.

Comment: unfortunately this also returns 1 if the process is in a "zombie" state, so doesn't tell you if a process is dead, just whether a process with that PID exists on the system somewhere (for example if you have an open stream to a process, this will return 1 even if the process has terminated). Also note that PID's can be re-used by the OS...

Answer (score 62):

The difference between the `Process.getpgid` and `Process::kill` approaches seems to be what happens when the pid exists but is owned by another user. `Process.getpgid` will return an answer, `Process::kill` will throw an exception `(Errno::EPERM)`.

Based on that, I recommend `Process.getpgid`, if just for the reason that it saves you from having to catch two different exceptions.

Here's the code I use:

```
begin
  Process.getpgid( pid )
  true
rescue Errno::ESRCH
  false
end
```

Comment: How do I kill a process owned by another user?

Comment: oneliner: `(Process.getpgid(pid) rescue nil).present?`

Answer (score 47):

@John T, @Dustin: Actually, guys, I perused the Process rdocs, and it looks like

```
Process.getpgid( pid )
```

is a less violent means of applying the same technique.

Comment: I found that this can return false positives (it reports running when in fact it wasn't) on the latest Ubuntu. I don't know why but I in this thread only the solution from @balu seemed to work for me.

Comment: I'm guessing this isn't a cross-platform solution. (It doesn't work on Windows, right?)

Comment: I think the implication here is that `kill 0` is "violent" -- this is a mistake.  The docs say: "If sig is 0, then no signal is sent, but error checking is still performed; this can be used to check for the existence of a process ID or process group ID."

Comment: Getting `NotImplementedError (getpgid() function is unimplemented on this machine)` in windows machine. any help?

Comment: @ManivannanJeganathan This doesn't work on Windows. Use another solution instead. (Maybe [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/325088/1157054)).

Answer (score 33):

For child processes, other solutions like sending a signal won't behave as expected: they will indicate that the process is still running when it actually exited.

You can use [Process.waitpid](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Process.html#method-c-waitpid2) if you want to check on a process that you spawned yourself. The call won't block if you're using the `Process::WNOHANG` flag and `nil` is going to be returned as long as the child process didn't exit.

Example:

```
pid = Process.spawn('sleep 5')
Process.waitpid(pid, Process::WNOHANG) # => nil
sleep 5
Process.waitpid(pid, Process::WNOHANG) # => pid
```

If the pid doesn't belong to a child process, an exception will be thrown (`Errno::ECHILD: No child processes`).

The same applies to [Process.waitpid2](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Process.html#method-c-waitpid2).

Comment: I found this to be more reliable than above mentioned solutions. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, that's most reliable answer for spawned processes. For non-spawned by us processes, the other solutions are fine.

Comment: This seems to be the only answer that works on windows, at least for me :D

Answer (score 7):

This is how I've been doing it:

```
def alive?(pid)
  !!Process.kill(0, pid) rescue false
end
```

Comment: You generally don't ever want to use `rescue` like that, but it seems justifiable here.

Answer (score 5):

You can try using

```
Process::kill 0, pid
```

where pid is the pid number, if the pid is running it should return 1.

Answer (score 4):

Under Linux you can obtain a lot of attributes of running programm using proc filesystem:

```
File.read("/proc/#{pid}/cmdline")
File.read("/proc/#{pid}/comm")
```

Answer (score 0):

A `*nix`-only approach would be to shell-out to `ps` and check if a `\n` (new line) delimiter exists in the returned string.

***Example IRB Output***

```
1.9.3p448 :067 > `ps -p 56718`                                                          
"  PID TTY           TIME CMD\n56718 ttys007    0:03.38 zeus slave: default_bundle   \n"
```

***Packaged as a Method***

```
def process?(pid)  
  !!`ps -p #{pid.to_i}`["\n"]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I've dealt with this problem before and yesterday I compiled it into the "[process_exists](https://github.com/wilsonsilva/process_exists)" gem.

It sends the null signal (0) to the process with the given pid to check if it exists. It works even if the current user does not have permissions to send the signal to the receiving process.

Usage:

```
require 'process_exists'

pid = 12
pid_exists = Process.exists?(pid)
```