# In Ruby telling if a system process is still alive?

Tags: ruby, unix

If I start an app in the following way

```
cmd = "some_app &"
`#{cmd}`
```

How can I find out if the process is still alive? I know there are various ways of
getting the pid of the running app, and I could then check if that was still available via
`ps -ef`. However that would only tell me if there was an process that existed with the same pid, when the app could have been killed along time previously. The same issue exists with
`ps -ef | grep some_app` approach.

Anybody any ideas of a clean way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$alive = true
Thread.new do
    `some_app`
    $alive = false
end

if $alive
  ...
```

Answer (score 4):

This cannot be done in the general case; Unix's facilities for manipulating processes are limited and not well integrated with the rest of the kernel API (there is, for instance, no way to get a file descriptor for a process, that could be passed to `select` or similar).

You can use the [`wait` family of functions](http://linux.die.net/man/2/wait) to block or poll for a child process having exited.  You can install a handler for `SIGCHLD` and be notified asynchronously when a child exits.  And, with cooperation from the child process, you can use a pipe or socket to get more detail on what's going on.  However, with active *lack* of cooperation from the child, you're hosed (for instance, a child that itself forks, exits in the child, and calls [`setsid`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/setsid) in the grandchild has escaped `wait` tracking in the original parent).

Those are pretty much your options, unless you are prepared to go deep into the land of system specific code (for instance, some people have done clever things with `ptrace`, which is normally for debuggers, to solve the sorts of problem you're looking at -- but I would not try it except as a last resort).

Comment: Hmmmm you've got me thinking, presumably every process has a parent process of the current running ruby interpreter somewhere up the process tree. Would it not just be a matter of working down the tree starting at the master process of the ruby interpreter? (I'm guessing this is what you were kinda saying with ptrace).

Comment: Yes, except a process cannot `wait` for anything but its direct children, there is no portable way to walk the process tree, and if an intermediate child exits, everything below that point gets "reparented" to process 1 ("init"), so even if you *could* walk the process tree, you wouldn't necessarily be able to find all your descendants.

Answer (score 2):

Researched this on a prior project...

Apparently the common practice is use `Process.kill(0, pid)` to probe a pid to see whether
a signal can be sent. This method will return true only if the process both exists *and* the caller has permission to signal it. A return value of false can mean that process doesn't exist **or the user doesn't have appropriate permission** or the pid is the wrong type (i.e a string) or ...

You can catch the particular exception that indicates non-existence, `Errno::ESRCH`, "No such process", distinguishing that from lack of permission etc.

`def process_exists?(pid)
   begin
     Process.kill(0, pid)
   rescue Errno::ESRCH # "No such process"
     return false
   rescue Errno::EPERM # "Operation not permitted"
     # at least the process exists
     return true
   else
     return true
   end
end`

Obviously *not* bulletproof but it's a start...

Comment: This actually doesn't work, (unless I'm missing something). As I stated in the question, if the process dies and a new process gets assigned the same pid it'll show a false positive.

Comment: This doesn't satisfy "how do I tell if a process is still alive", but it does satisfy another important question, "How can I tell if a PID exists?" (Which has been asked elsewhere:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325082/how-can-i-check-from-ruby-whether-a-process-with-a-certain-pid-is-running .)