# Ruby wait for process to exit

Tags: ruby

In ruby, I need to implement a logic where the current Ruby process automatically terminates when the parent process exits/crashes.

I can get the parent's process ID using Process.ppid, but all the wait methods on the Process module are for child process.

Is there a way to wait for the exit of non-child process?

Comment: Are you talking about processes or threads? In case of threads the creating process should take care that all threads are cleaned up in a good manner. The Ruby documentation is pretty good: [thread](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Thread.html), [process](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Process.html)

Comment: Process! I am using it on windows and need wait for exit of Windows process.

Answer (score 1):

@Ashutosh, check the following sample that presents a solution for the logic you mentioned.

```ruby
Process.fork { 
  ppid = Process.ppid
  while true do
    puts "Dad is #{ppid}" 
    sleep(1)
    if ppid != Process.ppid
      puts 'Dad has gone to sleep, so have I'
      Process.exit!(true)
    end
  end
}
for i in 1..5 do
  puts "I am #{Process.pid}"
  sleep(2)
end
```

Output:

```
I am 3299
Dad is 3299
Dad is 3299
I am 3299
Dad is 3299
Dad is 3299
I am 3299
Dad is 3299
Dad is 3299
I am 3299
Dad is 3299
Dad is 3299
I am 3299
Dad is 3299
Dad is 3299
Dad is 3299
Dad has gone to sleep, so have I
```

Explanation:

- There is a child process which is forked by `Process.fork`
- At the beginning, we save the parent id, since after the parent is terminated, `Process.ppid` returns another pid, which does not belong to the real parent.
- When parent terminates, `Process.ppid` returns another pid
- For the sake of safety, use `Process.exit!` to terminate the child process

For more information, take a look at the [`Process` doc](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Process.html).

According to the documentation, the `Process` class works in a very varied way on different OS.

Comment: This doesn't work on Windows. I have read the Process doc multiple times but it doesn't work... Even tried everything mentioned on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325082/how-can-i-check-from-ruby-whether-a-process-with-a-certain-pid-is-running but still no luck so far.

Comment: Also, I can't start any child process for monitoring.